# How to find a file location by file name, and file name only, using get_ciminstance in powershell?

Tags: powershell, file, filter, directory

I'm trying to write a script that will retrieve a specific file's properties across multiple computers. I was using get-childitem to do this until I realized that only retrieves locally. I've read that get-ciminstance can be used to do this for remote machines, however, all the examples I've seen use full paths to find the files. My script assumes the location could be anywhere on the C drive, so it only looks for the location based on the file's name. So far I've tried several variations of code using get-ciminstance, but all either produce nothing or have the wrong query structure.

Here's what I have right now, and it's what I believe is the closest to being correct, but I'm not sure:

```
Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $PC -ClassName CIM_DataFile | select Name | Where-Object { $_.Name -like  "install.properties"}
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice link.  https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/powertips/b/tips/posts/accessing-individual-files-and-folders-remotely-via-wmi Name is the full path, with double backslashes.  The filter language is like sql.  You can't use invoke-command?

```
Get-CimInstance CIM_DataFile -Filter 'name = "c:\\users\\admin\\foo\\file.json"'
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I have looked over that link before, but if Name is actually the full path, then I suppose I'm trying to do something else. I need to use the actual name of the file as the filter value since the file path is unknown. Is that possible?